# How can I set a label color to that of a dynamic resource in C#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code that I have:

```
grid.Children.Add(new Label
{
   Text = "00",
   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   TextColor = " {DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
});
```

But it does not accept that format for the setting of Dynamic resource.

Comment: TextColor = " {DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"  This applies to XAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are using the wrong syntax to do it, try something like this:

```
TextColor = (Color) App.Current.Resources["PageBackgroundColor"];
```

If your dynamic resource keeps changing at runtime do something like below:

```
yourLabel.SetDynamicResource (VisualElement.TextColorProperty, "PageBackgroundColor");
```

In case there is a query, please revert

Comment: But this way it is not dynamically changing when the color of the dynamic resources changes, because it assigns the actual color at the moment of running.

Comment: @HugoLogmans I have added a way to do it dynamically if your Resource changes on the fly multiple times

Answer (score -1):

```
yourLabel.SetDynamicResource (Label.TextColorProperty, "PageBackgroundColor");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.